# Handling network errors in SvgPicture.network()

Tags: flutter, flutter-network

I am using the [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package and I want to retry loading of the svg if any network error occurs (unstable internet connection, server error, etc.).

My code now looks like this:

```
SvgPicture.network(
  imageUrl,
  width: 24.0, height: 24.0,
  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace SvgPicture.network with SvgPicture.memory like this:

```html
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class SvgPictureNetwork extends StatefulWidget {
  const SvgPictureNetwork({
    super.key,
    required this.url,
    this.placeholderBuilder,
    this.errorBuilder,
  });

  final String url;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext)? placeholderBuilder;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext)? errorBuilder;

  @override
  State<SvgPictureNetwork> createState() => _SvgPictureNetworkState();
}

class _SvgPictureNetworkState extends State<SvgPictureNetwork> {
  Uint8List? _svgFile;
  var _shouldCallErrorBuilder = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadSVG();
  }

  Future<void> _loadSVG() async {
    try {
      final svgLoader = SvgNetworkLoader(widget.url);
      final svg = await svgLoader.prepareMessage(context);

      if (!mounted) return;

      setState(() {
        _shouldCallErrorBuilder = svg == null;
        _svgFile = svg;
      });
    } catch (_) {
      setState(() {
        _shouldCallErrorBuilder = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_shouldCallErrorBuilder && widget.errorBuilder != null) {
      return widget.errorBuilder!(context);
    }

    if (_svgFile == null) {
      return widget.placeholderBuilder?.call(context) ?? const SizedBox();
    }

    return SvgPicture.memory(_svgFile!);
  }
}
```